# C# Class with generic property

Tags: c#, json, generics

I'm trying to map api responses to a custom api class. The Api always returns these json fields:

```
Success (true/false)
Paginator (object)
Data (object)
```

Ok, first both field are no problem as they are always the same. 
But the Data is - depending on the endpoint - of a other class (`User`, `Group` etc.)

For all these endpoints, I have an entity class like user.cs etc.

How can I dynamically map an user object to the `ApiResponseClass` described above?

I don't want to make `ApiResponseClasses` for each endpoint, if possible.

Sorry for the formatting, I'm on mobile.

Comment: Please try to provide us with some code

Comment: More specifically, try to give a [MCVE].  Have you tried making a base class for all these objects?  Which serializer are you using?  As is, this question is either too broad or not clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public class ApiResponse<T>
{
    public bool Success { get; set;}
    public object Paginator { get; set;}
    public T Data { get; set; }
}

public class User
{
    public string Name {get;set;}
    //Other properties
}
```

Then depending on how you're currently reading from the Api you'd use `<ApiResponse<User>>` which means that T Date in the ApiReponse is set to the User type.

e.g. if you're using HttpClient Type

```
using (var client = new HttpClient())
{
    var response = await client.GetAsync("http://yoururl.com")
    var jsonString = await task.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
    var model = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ApiResponse<User>>(jsonString);
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much. Worked like a charm. Generics were new to me.

Answer (score 4):

Create a class using generics and set the `Data` property to the generic parameter.

For example

```
public class ApiResponse<TData> {
    public bool Success  { get; set; }
    public object Paginator { get; set; }
    public TData Data  { get; set; }
}

public class ApiResponse: ApiResponse<object> {
}
```

And can then be used in the end points like this on the server

```
public ApiResponse<User> MyUserAction() { ... }

public ApiResponse<Group> MyGroupAction() { ... }
```

or even on client side when deserializing json

```
ApiResponse<User> response = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ApiResponse<User>>(json);
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use generics:

```
public class ApiResponse<T>
{
    public bool IsSuccess { get; set; }
    public object Paginator { get; set; }
    public T Data { get; set; }
}
```

When an API endpoint will return `User` as response, just instantiate the `ApiResponse` class:

```
var response = new ApiResponse<User>
```